# Windows Home Server - raid or extra storage

Tags: raid, windows-home-server

I recently stuck another disk into my WHS machine and when the wizard popped up and asked me if I wanted to use it to expand storage or as a duplicate for the current storage I clicked something but don't remember what it was.

How can I find out if it's set-up to use the extra disk as more storage or a software raid?

If it's setup as extra storage, is there a way to change it to act as a RAID?

Answer (score 4):

Technically WHS doesn't use RAID. Microsoft came up with their own implementation, if you mean is there a way to change which option is used after the initial setup then you can tell WHS that you want to remove the drive, it will make sure all the data on it is stored somewhere else, then you can add the drive in again and select the option you want.

Not sure if this can be done on the fly, but if someone else knows all the better!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this [Addon](http://www.tentaclesoftware.com/whsdiskmanagement/) for WHS, i have used it for over a year it has some good information about whats going on under the hood